# x,y data of matplotlib arc

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I get the `x,y` data that is used to create the smooth arc by `matplotlib.patches.Arc()`.?

The documentation does not say anything about this and the closest thing I have obtained is through `get_verts()`, which gives me some sort of bounding box (dotted line in the image below) and not the arc itself.

[image]

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything because why would you need this data? From the docs -> matplotlib.patches.Arc(xy, width, height, *args). You are inputting width, height and origin. You can get the x, y data by inputting the equivalent arguments into the equation of an ellipse: (x-h)^2/(a^2) + (y-k)^2/(b^2) = 1. a = b in the case of a circle.

Comment: The short answer is: There is no way to get the coordinates of the arc from the `Arc` object, because those coordinates are calculated at draw time from the equation of an ellipse.

Comment: @David The equation of an ellipse you have described is with zero rotation. The equation along with the rotation component can be coded in, but since I already had the arc in my code, I thought maybe I can make use of it.

Comment: You know the origin of the ellipse. You also know the domain of the function: it is (-width, width). You can easily solve for all (x, y) coordinates by rewriting the ellipse equation in the form y = f(x) and iterating over the domain to get the range. But yes, I do understand your desire to return (x, y) coordinates from a drawer function however, it's always easier to "get stuff" when it's already "done"!